# Do I need to cache the In-App purchase in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, windows-phone

Do I need to cache the fact of having a license of In-App purchase? The user there may be no internet connection for example. I do not want check the license on each application start up, with the method.

```
await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

Is there a need to cache In-App purchase in IsolatedStorage? For example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get list of In-app purchased
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<List<string>> GetOwnedItems()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        List<string> items = (List<string>)settings["PurchasedProducts"];

        if (!items.Any()) //TODO If no purchases, call this block one time, no more!!!
        {
            ListingInformation li = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            items = new List<string>();

            foreach (string key in li.ProductListings.Keys)
            {
                if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive)
                    items.Add(key);
            }

           //Save to IsolatedStorage
           settings["PurchasedProducts"] = items;
        }

        return items;
    }

    public async void PurcaseItem(string itemKey)
    {
        if (!Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[itemKey].IsActive)
        {
            ListingInformation li = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            string pID = li.ProductListings[itemKey].ProductId;

            string receipt = await Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID, false);

            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            //TODO Add key to Isolated storage
            List<string> items = ((List<string>)settings["PurchasedProducts"]).Add(pID);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to cache In-App purchases.
The Windows Phone operating system does that for you in the [LicenseInformation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation).

If there is no Internet Connection the user is also not able to do any in-app purchses. So you don't have to fear a loss of user licenses.